# How to use shell to continuously process tail -f new lines in real time？

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tail

There is a file on the linux server, which new lines appended to it **aperiodically**. I need to process new line, parse it and use other command or script to process it . Check the file periodically is not acceptable, I need a **real time** solution. No other language (Python, Perl) is available on the server, only shell.

Now, I'm trying to assign the new line to a shell variable, and then process it. But can not find a good way to do that. Another problem is  I need to rely on some result former when processing new lines. For example, when I process the 11th line, maybe the 5th line result is required. So some variables needed to store the result before, and I need to use them in the loop.

Any solution or any better suggestion for my case?

Comment: *"...  or any better suggestion..."* - you never stated what you are doing, and you did not provide your code. It is not possible to provide suggestions to improve what you are doing.

Comment: @jww Thanks for your comment. Sorry to make you confuse, I thought I have made it clear in the question. My goal is to process the new line in real time when a line appended to a file.  So, get the new line immediately is the core problem.  The only solution I could think out is use the tail -f, but I can't write the code under the condition I described, so I ask this question. The better suggestion means, except use the tail -f,  any other command could be used. Hoping your are satisfied with the explanation.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but... it looks like all you have done is posted your requirements and asked someone to write the code for you. I don't see any effort to solve the problem yourself. Surely a little searching would have revealed how to assign to a shell variable.

Comment: @jww That could be a misunderstanding.  It's not as simple as just assign to a shell variable, I won't ask question like that.I have searched a lot but didn't find the useful result,  so I ask the question. I missed the 'read' command could 
 continuously read the line in a loop via pip line. And shuerguo's answer use the local variable to solve the second problem.  I didn't mean to ask others to write code for me, I just need the idea.

Comment: Please put the actual file in your question! You can redact sensitive data. But your question is way too vague right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the code below

```
#!/bin/bash
process_new_line() {
    local var= '' #declare some local variables here 
    read
    while true
    do
        #process $REPLY 
        #The new line content is in the variable $REPLY 
        #store the result in the local variable according to your rules.
        read
    done
}

tail -f the_file | process_new_line
```

Use a function will solve your problem. You could use local variable to store the result, and $REPLY hold the new line content.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Thank you @shuerguo, it works. I  didn't know the variable $REPLY before, figure out the meaning just now. But I believe use a self defined variable may be better. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: This is great, but as @iBug points out, you should elaborate on WHY this works.   It took me some digging to figure out that $REPLY is a feature of 'read'.   It would be especially useful contextually to explain this in your answer so people are able to conceptualize what makes your answer work.

Comment: This give me the error `local: '': not a valid identifier`

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
tail -f filename | while read -r line; do
    : # process the line
done
```

This will be real-time except to the extent that lines are buffered.  If the buffering bothers you, there are utilities like `stdbuf` to shrink the buffers.

You didn't mention whether your system has awk.  It is required by the POSIX standard for Unix systems.  If you have it, it is excellent for *"calculating, replacing some characters"*, etc.:

```
tail -f filename | awk 'awk code'
```

Comment: Thank you @John1024. When processing new lines, I need rely on some result before. For example, when I process the 11th line, maybe the 5th line result is required, so some variables needed to store some result, and I need to use them in the loop. It's my fault not make it clear in the question. BTW, I use awk in my code, but it's not enough, I still use some other command and script.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Germinate Both shell and awk are perfectly capable of saving variables between iterations.  Both can do arithmetic and substitutions on variables.  It sounds like a good next step for you would be to read a tutorial on [shell](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+tutorial) or [awk](https://www.google.com/search?q=awk+tutorial).

Comment: @Germinate Also, from what you have told me so far, if your system has it, `awk` is likely the better choice.